# OpsCenter cannot recognize Cassandra nodes in the same network

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-java-driver, opscenter

I am experimenting with Datestax OpsCenter 5.2 and Cassandra 2.1.7.  One trouble I encountered is that OpsCenter daemon (i.e., the server) seems to try to connect to the Cassandra agents using the `broadcast_rpc_address`, which is blocked by the security group (because `broadcast_rpc_address` is a public IP on AWS).

### Details

The cluster has three nodes (10.0.0.0/24 is the subnet of a VPC on AWS, 52.x.x.x is a public IP)

#### Node0

cassandra.yaml: broadcast_address=10.0.0.100, rpc_address=10.0.0.100, broadcast_rpc_address=52.2.3.100

address.yaml: stomp_interface=10.0.0.99, local_interface=10.0.0.100, agent_rpc_broadcast_address=10.0.0.100

#### Node1

cassandra.yaml: broadcast_address=10.0.0.101, rpc_address=10.0.0.101, broadcast_rpc_address=52.2.3.101

address.yaml: stomp_interface=10.0.0.99, local_interface=10.0.0.101, agent_rpc_broadcast_address=10.0.0.101

#### Node2

cassandra.yaml: broadcast_address=10.0.0.102, rpc_address=10.0.0.102, broadcast_rpc_address=52.2.3.102

address.yaml: stomp_interface=10.0.0.99, local_interface=10.0.0.102, agent_rpc_broadcast_address=10.0.0.102

#### OpsCenter Node

Deployed in the same subnet

ip=10.0.0.99

### Symptons

After adding "10.0.0.100, 10.0.0.101, 10.0.0.102" to the "Add Cluster" window on OpsCenter web console, I got the following in `opscenterd.log`:

```
2015-09-04 11:05:38+0000 []  INFO: New Cassandra host 52.2.3.100 discovered
2015-09-04 11:05:38+0000 []  INFO: New Cassandra host 52.2.3.101 discovered
...
2015-09-04 11:05:43+0000 []  WARN: [control connection] Error connecting to 52.2.3.100: errors=Timed out creating connection, last_host=None
2015-09-04 11:05:43+0000 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'52.2.3.100': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection, last_host=None',)})
```

Notice OpsCenter tries to connect to nodes via their `broadcast_rpc_address`, which is blocked by the security group.  This is despite I have set `agent_rpc_broadcast_address` to subnet IPs.

**Question 1**

Is this the correct behavior of OpsCenter?  Why `agent_rpc_broadcast_address` is not used?

**Question 2**

If I change `broadcast_rpc_address` to subnet IPs, then OpsCenter connects fine.  But this prevents my clients from connecting, because non-seed nodes will have their subnet IP reported by seed nodes to the client, which is not reachable by the client.

I can also open up the security group to the OpsCenter server, but this is risky and requires going through the gateway.

So how should I solve the problem in this case?

**Thoughts**

The core of this problem is how to "intelligently" decide which IP to connect to depending on whether a client is inside or outside a subnet.  All documentation I have seen does not make it clear how this works.

Thanks for any help.

### Addition 1

Would be grateful if you could also clarify how rpc(thrift) and native(binary) protocol are used by client and OpsCenter.

I have the impression that rpc is deprecated in favor of native protocol, but will this affect inter-node and client-node connection?

Comment: comment out broadcast_rpc_address and it will probably work

Comment: @LHWizard, commenting broadcast_rpc_address will cause clients trying to connect to the subnet IP (for any non-seed node).  For a client not in the subnet, this will fail.

Comment: My intention is to get both a) an OpsCenter in the same subnet and b) a client outside the subnet, to work.

Comment: you might try setting rpc_address to 0.0.0.0

Comment: also your statement in Question 2 is wrong. The seeds don't report ip addresses to the clients.

Comment: @LHWizard, if seed nodes don't report ip addresses, how does a client connect to non-seed nodes?  If I have a cluster of 100 nodes, do I have to specify all of them manually for the client to connect?

Comment: @stackoverflower driver does a select on `system.peers` on nodes it has access to and builds topology map this way: https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cluster.py#L2155-L2160 || https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/b1e6ad868e147e15740b8793a0e2966ca1b66910/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ControlConnection.java#L544. Address in system.peers is pretty much broadcast_rpc_address || rpc_address IIRC.

Comment: @arre, thanks, that makes things much clearer.  I will write a blog post about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1
>
> Is this the correct behavior of OpsCenter? Why agent_rpc_broadcast_address is not used?

It is at the moment. OpsCenter (via underlying python driver) gets rpc address from Cassandra itself, so it gets values of `broadcast_rpc_address`, which are not reachable. `agent_rpc_broadcast_address` is used to connect to the agents, not Cassandra nodes themselves.

I’m not sure why are you blocking access to the broadcast address from the same subnet (same security group even?) while also allowing access to it from outside the subnet.

> Would be grateful if you could also clarify how rpc(thrift) and native(binary) protocol are used by client and OpsCenter.

As of 5.2 OpsCenter does not use thrift to communicate to Cassandra, relying on native protocol for opscenterd and native protocol + jmx for agents.

Comment: Access to broadcast address is blocked because the gateway routes the request, which masquerades the source IP to a public one, which is blocked by the security group (the public IP is dynamically assigned, so I cannot easily whitelist it).  Everything would be fine if it connects to the private IP.

Comment: Does this mean clients have static addresses? How do you whitelist your application?

Comment: Applications are in another network, whose gateway is whitelisted.  It looks like I probably should deploy OpsCenter to that network instead of the Cassandra one.